# Some images not found 404 in localhost

Tags: images, 404-error, localhost

I just transferred a WordPress installation from the domain to my localhost. I did all the usual steps: copy files, export DB and replace `domain.com` with `localhost`, update `wp-config.php` and refresh permalinks. All pages and custom rewrite rules work, but some images are giving a 404.

When I check those images on the actual domain it all works fine, but something doesn't look right; if I check the url of the image it points to this path:

```
http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_0425-185x185.jpg
```

But this file doesn't exist! I looked in the uploads folder through FTP and the file isn't there, only `IMG_0425-185x185-150x150.jpg` exists. Note that `185x185` is part of the original filename but `150x150` is added by WP.

In localhost the image doesn't show up (404), which makes sense.

Why is the image showing up on the domain when it doesn't even exist? Is WordPress resolving the image to the generated thumbnail somehow? Why isn't it working on the localhost if this is the case?

**Edit:**

This is what makes no sense. How is this possible? Maybe the cache has something to do?
As you can see no trace of `IMG_0425-185x185.jpg` in the folder (??) but `IMG_0425-185x185-150x150.jpg` exists.

[image]

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Comment: in my case, a plugin named as "WebP Express" create a htaccess file in uploads folder that restrict my access to some images.
try rename or remove it and see if the problem still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `home` and `siteurl` in your `wp_options` table is not enough unfortunately. You will still have your post content with your non-localhost URL (`http://domain.com`) causing your website to not display properly on your localhost.

Once you've downloaded and imported your database to your localhost. Follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://localhost/wordpress/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not there in your FTP client - therefore not on your server - it's not going to be showing up on your site. So it's almost certainly a caching thing in your browser, have you tried clearing it or doing a hard refresh? WordPress's rewrite won't fallback to the thumbnail if the original image isn't there. the `.htaccess` will just load up the `index.php` which will throw a 404.

The other thing I would check is to make sure the URL is pointed to where you think it's pointed. WordPress stores all it's image links as an absolute URL in the DB. And unless you do a find+replace when you transfer a site, that won't get updated. You said you were moving the site around and it's quite possible you're actually loading the image from an older server.

Comment: Check the image I added. That's the strange thing. On the domain the image shows up even though the url points to an image that doesn't exist. I searched/replaced everything like I always do, never had this issue. It's weird. I deactivated the cache and still 404. I repeated this process a couple times, same thing.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? What kind of plugins do you have installed? Although I can't imagine a caching plugin would do that as all the one's I've looked at use output caching just to take the load off the DB and PHP DOM building. But you're still loading assets from the server.

Comment: I'm in the process of rebuilding all the thumbnails with http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/. 2 out of 259, 3 out of 259... let's see how it goes. I deactivated the Super Cache plugin in localhost and problem persists.

Comment: Good luck. I've had good results with [this option](http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) if that doesn't help.

Comment: Finished, didn't work. I'm thinking that maybe some images have been uploaded with different permissions, so they don't show up in the FTP with my credentials. I may have to contact the client and see if this is the problem, because the images **show up** in the domain but not in the FTP. Can't think of anything else other than that...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's permissions. Go to the wp-content folder in the console and type:

```
chmod -R 767 uploads
```

[Codex permissions info.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)